# Shared preferrence doesn't work

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use Shared Preferences in my app to see if the question has been answered or no.
Everytime I use it it doesn't work.
Can someone help me to turn it in Shared Preferences?

Here is the activity of the status if the question has been answered:

```
public class Question extends Activity{
boolean answered;

int id;
String Answer;

public Question(int i){
    id = i;
    answered = false;
}
}
```

And when he answer it gets to true (answered = true)

Here is the activity to get if it answered show something if not show something else:

```
//activity    

      items = new ArrayList<Question>();
  }
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
      int id = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
      if(Question.get(id).answered){
        // do something
      }  
  }
}
```

I've tried to make it works in Shared Preferences, but it didn't work.
This works now, but I want it to save and load.

Comment: first read Officle document : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: You should consider changing your title because the code you posted does not contain any SharedPreferences. It certainly won't work if you aren't actually using it.

Comment: What I wrote is part of an activity.

Answer (score 0):

To save a value whithin an activity you can use the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString( getString(R.id.your_key), value);
editor.apply();
```

To read the value within an activity you can use this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String value = sharedPrefs.getString(getString(R.id.your_key), "");
```

Comment: I know, but what I want to know is how ti save boolean for a variable int?
(There is 5 questions, I want to save boolean for this five questions in one, is this possible? )

Comment: You can convert the boolean to int values and save the int. 
E.g. if question 2,3 and 5 have already been answered the int will be 01101